# Getting a strange error while trying to draw an image in java?

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent, graphics2d

I am trying to move a function from the main class to a sub-class in a small game I'm making. I have copied and pasted the function from the main class into a sub-class and for some reason I am getting this error:

```
no suitable method found for drawImage(java.awt.Image,int,int,pony)
method java.awt.Graphics2D.drawImage(java.awt.BufferedImage, java.awt.BufferedImageOp, int, int) is not applicable; (actual argument java.awt.Image cannot be converted to java.awt.BufferedImage by method invocation conversion);
```

This is the function:

```
public void explode(Graphics g)
{
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

    int i=0;
    float angle = 0.03f;
    float PI = 3.14159f;
    int x2,y2;
    int r=40;

    while(r<200)
    {
        while (angle < 2 * PI)
        {
            x2 = (int)this.x + (int) (Math.cos(angle)*r);
            y2 = (int)this.y + (int) (Math.sin(angle)*r);

            g2d.drawImage(sparkles[i].getImage(), x2, y2,this);

            angle+=0.1;
            i+=1;
        }
        i=0;
        angle=0.03f;
        r+=5;
    }

}
```

Here is the function call in the main class:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

    for(int i=0;i<curPonies;i++)
    {
       if(ponies[i].colliding())
       {
          ponies[i].explode(g);
       }
    }
}
```

If I move the explode function into the main class it works perfectly, but if I try to call it from another class I get the error above. If anyone can tell me why this happens, I would very much appreciate the help.

Thank you very much!

Comment: `java.awt.Graphics2D.drawImage(java.awt.BufferedImage, java.awt.BufferedImageOp, int, int)` Where it asks foe a BufferedImageOp parameter (second parameter), you put an int. For the last pareter, needing an int, you put put an object (`this`). It also states: actual argument java.awt.Image cannot be converted to java.awt.BufferedImage by method invocation conversion, meaning the Image your putting in cant be converted to BufferedImage. If you know it is a BufferedImage, cast it. `(BufferedImage)  getImage()`

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example).

Answer (score 1):

Call in this way

```
g2d.drawImage(sparkles[i].getImage(), x2, y2, null); // if observer is not known
```

Look at [Graphics#drawImage(Image img,int x,int y,ImageObserver observer)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawImage%28java.awt.Image,%20int,%20int,%20java.awt.image.ImageObserver%29).

[java.awt.Graphics2D](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html#drawImage%28java.awt.image.BufferedImage,%20java.awt.image.BufferedImageOp,%20int,%20int%29) is sub-class of [java.awt.Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawImage%28java.awt.Image,%20int,%20int,%20java.awt.image.ImageObserver%29).

---

**In your case last argument `this` must implement [ImageObserver](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/ImageObserver.html).**

```
g2d.drawImage(sparkles[i].getImage(), x2, y2,this);
//last argument this must be an ImageObserver
```

Comment: Hes using Graphics2d, which requires different parameters. You should point out that using `null` as the final parameter value really makes a difference, so he understands why he's comming across this error. This error is typically easier to find when not using Graphics2d, since theres not as much confusion with overloaded methods

Comment: `java.awt.Graphics2D` is sub-class of `java.awt.Graphics`.

Comment: Look at last line of my post. Now we don't know what is `this` here?

Comment: The last line of your post is good; as long as he understands what was causing the problem, so he doesnt end up back here with the same one :P